# Regex, replace all underscore and special char with spaces?

Tags: python, regex

so im trying to replace all special chars into spaces, using regex:
my code works, but it wont replace underscore, what should i do?

code:

```
    new_str = re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', new_str)
```

its working on all of the other special chars but not underscore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Underscore is considered a "word character" in PCRE regular expressions. If what you want to match is "anything that is not a word character or an underscore", try this:

```
new_str = re.sub(r'[\W_]', ' ', new_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

The underscore is part of the `\w` character group. Use this instead:

```
new_str = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ', new_str)
```

which is the same as `\w` but minus the underscore.

Comment: @qwrrty: In Python 2, unless you specify `re.UNICODE` or `re.LOCALE`, it won't.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_str = re.sub(r'[^\w]|_', ' ', new_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it, changed it to:

```
    new_str = re.sub(r'[\w_+]', ' ', new_str)
```